# How to identify which port is being listened in Python's SocketServer?

Tags: python, port, socketserver

I have a small application that spawns a number of ports (300 to be exact). When it spawns a socket it uses:

```
# when someone connects via socketlistener, do some stuff
class SocketListener((SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler)):
      print "Do some stuff"
```

Is there a way to tell within SocketListener what port someone connected on?

Comment: Can you attach the number when the ports are spawned?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you instantiate the class that inherits BaseRequestHandler, but this might help:

```
class SocketListener((SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler)):
    def handle(self):
        print self.server.server_name, self.server.server_port
```